# How can I limit the number of my decimals?

Tags: java, decimal, calculator

What method can I use to limit the decimal point inputted by the user? I was making a basic calculator but I want the input to be in decimal so I set the data type into float. But I also want to limit my decimal point not more than 6 decimal places. I would also like to send a message to the user if the input is more than 6 decimal places and allow it to input again by loop. How can I do that?

Comment: Use `BigDecimal`. It has methods that allow you to control the scale.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `BigDecimal` can help here.

`BigDecimal::scale()`

> Returns the scale of this BigDecimal. If zero or positive, the scale
> is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. If
> negative, the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the
> power of the negation of the scale. For example, a scale of -3 means
> the unscaled value is multiplied by 1000.

So you might do something like this:

```
var number = BigDecimal(userInput); 
var scale = nubmer.scale(); 
if (scale > MAXIMUM_SCALE){
  // display error message and ask for new input
}
```

In case if you want to just limit input to not more than 5 decimal places:

```
var number = BigDecimal(userInput).setScale(6);
```

[BigDecimal::scale()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale()) and [BigDecimal::setScale()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int))

Comment: `setScale(6)` might also be helpful.

Comment: What's the val supposed to be?

Comment: @ezekiel, it is https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference.html Local Variable Type Inference. The correct syntax is `var`.

Comment: @ezekiel, instead of `var` it is just can be `BigDecimal number` and `BigDecimal scale`

Comment: Anton Balaniuc i don't know but i tried this var number = BigDecimal(userInput); 
var scale = numer.scale(); 
if (scale > MAXIMUM_SCALE){
  // display error message and ask for new input
} it will show an error in numer. scale, why?

Comment: @ezekiel, there is a typo in variable name: `numer` however is should be `number`. I have updated the example